# How to fetch the Group that Contains only some specific Items in SQL?

Tags: sql

We have some records in a table. Different Items are linked with a particular group. As shown below, Item 20,21 belongs to GroupId 1, while Items 20,21,5 belongs to another GroupId 2.

```
     Id   GroupId    Item
-------------------------
 1   1      1        20
 2   2      1        21
 3   3      2        20
 4   4      2        21
 5   5      2         5
```

I want to fetch the GroupId from above table that only contains Item 20 and 21. So in above example it should return GroupId 1.

Can someone please suggest a way how to fetch the GroupId 1 ?

Below is the script to create and populate the Data table with above records

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
     Id INT IDENTITY, 
     GroupId INT, 
     Item INT 
)

INSERT INTO Data 
VALUES (1, 20), (1, 21), (2, 20), (2, 21), (2, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation by `GroupId` is one option here:

```
SELECT GroupId
FROM Data
GROUP BY GroupId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Item NOT IN (20, 21) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

See the demo running below.

### Demo

Comment: I was stuck on this for last 3 days and while asking the question somehow I was not able to add the image, so I was trying to add the image back, but you answered it correctly within a minute without the image. Thanks a lot for your response. This is what I needed.